# Git Tag, how to get editor like on commit for message?

Tags: git, tags

As I get an editor (vi) when doing a `git commit -m` I'd like to get an editor doing

`git tag myTagName -m`

as my comment will contain code with quotes and I'd like to avoid escaping it!

Comment: `git tag -a tagName -m`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When tagging, give the parameter `-a` so git can see that this tag is "annotated", then git will open your editor to input the text.

For example:

```
git tag -a v1.0
```

Comment: Note that Git does not necessarily open `vim`, it depends on the environment/config.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#_description):

> If one of `-a`, `-s`, or `-u <keyid>` is passed, the command creates a *tag* object, and requires a tag message. Unless `-m <msg>` or `-F <file>` is given, an editor is started for the user to type in the tag message.
>
> If `-m <msg>` or `-F <file>` is given and `-a`, `-s`, and `-u <keyid>` are absent, `-a` is implied.
>
> Otherwise, a tag reference that points directly at the given object (i.e., a lightweight tag) is created.

As you may know, there are several kinds of tags in Git. When you used `-m <msg>`, you were implying `-a` (annotated tag). If you want to see the editor to provide the message, while still creating an annotated tag, simply use `-a` instead.

Comment: nice and useful, i'd start with the answer and then explanation for the tl;dr s. thx